# webpack рендер .png

Tags: webpack

помогите с Webpack. не рендерит *.png
собирает в dist оно не отображает на странице . куда смотреть ? [image: webpack.config]

```html
<img src="<%=require('../../images/img.png').default%>"/>
```

[image: package.json]

Comment: если Вы используете обычный `html`(без шаблонизаторов аля `pug` или фреймворков аля `React`), то указывайте путь к изображению уже для собранного проекта, например `<img src="images/img.png" />`

Comment: Спасибо ! 
такой вариант пробовал и получал такой же результат

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```html
<img src="../../images/img.png"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо 
Этот вариант был изначально. не работает .

Answer (score 0):

Решено . возможно кому-то поможет :
был пробел в пути "/> после <%= require....